# WP Customizer - what types of fields is it capable of supporting?

Tags: customization

I just found this reference of WP Customizer types of data input: https://gist.github.com/Abban/2968549

But I wonder if there's an option to have for instance a range slider? Something that would allow users to pick a value between `50px` and `200px` or between `1em` and `2em`? Ideally it should also allow switching units - like from `px` to `%` and vice versa.

Is this possible at all or does it require some custom extension? I also noticed that textarea isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference you pointed at just lists the **built-in** data input types. You can always add you own by creating a custom Customizer control. Follow [Otto's guide](http://ottopress.com/2012/making-a-custom-control-for-the-theme-customizer/) to create a textarea control. If you know your HTML, it should not be harder to implement a range slider.

I personally use the Customizer API to modify the `background-position` CSS property of the background image using the mouse dragging movement (see the [git repo](https://github.com/Fab1en/wp-theme-customizers)). Possibilities are endless !

Answer (score 0):

Both of these do not exist by default so you would need to add them yourself.

To add a custom option such as a new text area or a range slider you have to:

- Extend the `WP_Customize_Control` call with your options.
- Use `$wp_customize->add_setting` to add the setting (defaults)
- Use `$wp_customize->add_control` to call your custom options set in the class you extended.
- Use `$wp_customize->add_section` to render it in the Customizer
- Use `get_theme_mod` to get the value where you want it ouput.

ps. jQuery UI already comes with a range slider called `.slider` which is included by WordPress but you will need to `wp_enqueue_script` it.